# Propositional logic

Tags: logic, operators, logical-operators

I am trying to get from `(p→q) and (qr→s)` to `(pr→s)`, which is the same as `((not p) or q) and (not(q and r) or s)` to `(not(p and r) or s)`

Comment: Perhaps you'd clarify how this is a programming question. This looks like it should be on [maths.se]

Comment: Actually looks more like it's homework

Answer (score 1):

Theorem:

```hs
   p → q
= ¬p ∨ q       -- 1

   (q ∧ r) → s
= ¬(q ∧ r) ∨ s
=  ¬q ∨ ¬r ∨ s -- 2

   ¬p ∨ ¬r ∨ s -- from 1 and 2, q and ¬q cancel
= ¬(p ∧ r) ∨ s
=  (p ∧ r) → s
```

Qed.

---

Using Coq, we can prove this theorem as follows:

```
Coq < Theorem prop : forall p q r s : Prop, (p -> q) /\ (q /\ r -> s) -> p /\ r -> s.
1 subgoal

  ============================
   forall p q r s : Prop, (p -> q) /\ (q /\ r -> s) -> p /\ r -> s

prop < intros.
1 subgoal

  p : Prop
  q : Prop
  r : Prop
  s : Prop
  H : (p -> q) /\ (q /\ r -> s)
  H0 : p /\ r
  ============================
   s

prop < destruct H.
1 subgoal

  p : Prop
  q : Prop
  r : Prop
  s : Prop
  H : p -> q
  H1 : q /\ r -> s
  H0 : p /\ r
  ============================
   s

prop < destruct H0.
1 subgoal

  p : Prop
  q : Prop
  r : Prop
  s : Prop
  H : p -> q
  H1 : q /\ r -> s
  H0 : p
  H2 : r
  ============================
   s

prop < apply H1.
1 subgoal

  p : Prop
  q : Prop
  r : Prop
  s : Prop
  H : p -> q
  H1 : q /\ r -> s
  H0 : p
  H2 : r
  ============================
   q /\ r

prop < split.
2 subgoals

  p : Prop
  q : Prop
  r : Prop
  s : Prop
  H : p -> q
  H1 : q /\ r -> s
  H0 : p
  H2 : r
  ============================
   q

subgoal 2 is:
 r

prop < exact (H H0).
1 subgoal

  p : Prop
  q : Prop
  r : Prop
  s : Prop
  H : p -> q
  H1 : q /\ r -> s
  H0 : p
  H2 : r
  ============================
   r

prop < exact H2.
No more subgoals.

prop < Qed.
intros.
destruct H.
destruct H0.
apply H1.
split.
 exact (H H0).

 exact H2.

prop is defined
```

Hope that helps.